# Android - How to refresh cardview automatically like every 1 second

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have a recyclerview with cardview which is dynamically generated based on the ArrayList given as input to RecyclerViewAdpater that I fetch from Shared Preferences (which I saved it earlier in the code). I have run() method to continuously update and save the ArrayList in the shared preferences.
Now, I would like to refresh the cardview automatically based on the updated ArrayList in the Shared Preferences. I tried calling runOnUiThread while passing the list to the RecyclerViewAdapter but the app keeps crashing. Also not sure how can I implement notifydatasetchanged for continuous update as I know it can be done when clicked on cardView.
As this is first time I'm working on cardview as I have to show imageView and couple of textViews, not sure whether it is possible with any other views. So is this feasible or is there any other efficient way to achieve this using Native code ?

```
public class TestCode extends AppCompatActivity {


    List<BtnHandle> BtnHndl ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
        final Context myCt = this;


        BtnHndl = new ArrayList<>();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String BtnData = prefs.getString("btndata", "No name defined");
        JSONObject obj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(BtnData);
            jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("response");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject value = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String value1 = value.getString("val1");
                String value2 = value.getString("val2");
                String value3 = value.getString("val3");

                BtnHn.add(new BtnHandle(value1,value2,value3));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

                        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
                        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(myCt,BtnHndl);
                        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(myCt,3));
                        rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }





public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;
    private List<BtnHandle> mData ;
    Listenr mListn;


    public static interface Listenr{
        public void onClick(int postn);
    }

    public void setListener(Listenr listener){
        mListn = listener;
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<BtnHandle> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.value1.setText(mData.get(position).getValue1());
        holder.value2.setText(mData.get(position).getValue2());
        holder.value3.setText(mData.get(position).getValue3());

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView value1;
        TextView value2;
        TextView value3;

        CardView cardView ;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            value1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value1) ;
            value2  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value2) ;
            value3  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value3) ;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you to google `observer pattern` and how it is usually used in android: `LiveData` and `RxJava`

Comment: Sure I will check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the adapter without the list as an argument (initialize the adapter only once). Create a method in the adapter called **setAdapterItems** - inside, clear the internal list, add the new list, and call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you mentioned and called setAdapterItems from the activity for myAdapter, the view gets generated once but it is not getting updated. I tried to update the list by new Runnable() but the app keeps crashing.